# xtragrid binded to entity framework

Tags: xtragrid

my working environment is C#, Visual Studio 12, entity framework 5 DBContext, SQL Server 2008R2.
the generated entities sets are generated as Hash sets.

```
 xtraGrid.DataSource = _order.OrderLines;
```

when I type data in the new row, data disappears when focus lost.

With using  older entity framework, this logic was working.

What type should I choose for my entity set in order to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed type from HashSet to BindingList, and it works, God thank you.

Comment: Don't thank God, but thank to BindingList's changed notification events what I guess HashSet does not provide for the gridview. :)